# Molten metal flow due to high currents

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, electric-current, flow, metals

It is mentioned in the book "Ampere-Neumann Electrodynamics of Metals", Peter Graneau, that Carl Hering in 1923 operated furnaces by passing high currents through the molten metal pool. He observed (and made used of) molten metal flow due to the currents. How is the conductor motion explained?

Answer (score 0):

You may look, e.g., at Hering's US patent 988936. The electric current in a column of molten metal causes pinch-effect (as parallel currents attract each other), the resulting pressure causes further movement in the molten metal.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical model, the free electrons in a conductor are in thermal equilibrium with the atoms of the conductor. If an electric field is applied, the electrons are accelerated by the field between each collision with an atom. Then (on average) the momentum gain from this acceleration (in a direction opposite to the field) is transferred to an atom during the next collision.